# Jython Gstreamer

Tags: python, jython, gstreamer

Does anyone know where I can find a tutorial on how to use GStreamer with Jython? I have tried searching but with no luck. Using the Gstreamer-Python bindings I can get a python file to run with python but jython gives me ImportError: No module named pygst.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that it uses c bindings so you can not use in jython, sorry.

Comment: Do you know of another media library that I can use in jython?

Comment: @cguler quite right. I just went and tracked down the code to confirm.

Comment: well, since you're on jvm you can use any java library like [gstreamer-java](http://code.google.com/p/gstreamer-java/)

Comment: I cannot get gstreamer-java on a 64bit Windows JRE since GStreamer Windows uses 32bit dlls

Comment: @RedSoxFan: As far as I understood your question, your answer maybe:  http://groups.google.com/group/gstreamer-java/browse_thread/thread/57e9687e9b5e8697

Comment: @cguler Thanks for your responses. The problem is that most 64 bit windows systems run java using a 64bit JRE not a 32bit JRE. If I am wrong let me know but I have not been able to get gstreamer-java to run on a 64bit Windows System

Comment: well sorry friend, windows is alien to me, I definitely can't help you  beyond this point :(

Comment: @cguler Thanks, I have gstreamer-java running in ubuntu linux, I probably should try a 32bit windows machine to make sure that it is a 64bit issue and not a gstreamer windows issue but I guess since my original how to do this was answered this thread is done

Answer (score 1):

Keep an eye on JyNI (http://www.jyni.org). It is currently not able to use the GStreamer-bindings but hopefully will be in near future.

Until then you can use
JEP (https://github.com/mrj0/jep) or JPY (https://github.com/bcdev/jpy) to leverage the Python gstreamer-bindings in Java and thus also in Jython.

Also consider that JavaFX (included in Java as of Java8) has support for a number of streaming media formats. This would be the cleanest solution if you just want to play a video I suppose (because it adds no further dependencies, at least not in Java8-case).

Finally, consider to compile the Java-bindings for your system in 64 bit mode. Usually this is not too complicated via autotools etc.